# Entity Framework Core, how do I NOT save children records?

Tags: entity-framework-core

With the schema as shown below, when I save a `Vehicle`, it effects the `VehicleOrders` table which I do NOT want it to do.

I am using `[NotMapped]` but that does not work, other ideas?

From `Vehicle` and `UpdateVehicle` which does the update:

```cs
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<VehicleOrder> VehicleOrders { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<VehicleOrder> VehicleOrders1 { get; set; }
```

```cs
public async Task<RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle> UpdateVehicle(int id, RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle vehicle)
{
    OnVehicleUpdated(vehicle);

    var itemToUpdate = Context.Vehicles
                        .Where(i => i.Id == vehicle.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (itemToUpdate == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Item no longer available");
    }
        
    var entryToUpdate = Context.Entry(itemToUpdate);
    entryToUpdate.CurrentValues.SetValues(vehicle);
    entryToUpdate.State = EntityState.Modified;

    Context.SaveChanges();

    OnAfterVehicleUpdated(vehicle);

    return vehicle;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Steve Py, thank you. This is auto generated code from Radzen Blazor Studio (which on average is amazing), so gaining understanding. It is a Blazor Server app. `OnVehicleUpdated` and `OnAfterVehicleUpdated` don't do anything, they are just stubs.

```
var isSameReference = object.ReferenceEquals(itemToUpdate, vehicle);
```

is indeed `true` as the code was, so the whole thing can be boiled down to simply

```
    public async Task<RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle> UpdateVehicle(int id, RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return vehicle;
    }
```

So it must have, like you said, been loaded or `Attached` elsewhere.

There is a `Reset()` method avaliable in the code which detaches everything:

```
public void Reset() => Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

Now your `isSameReference` check is `false` which confirms.

While I could probably slim things down, for the sake of continuity with the auto generated code, I simply put in their `Reset()` at the top of the `Update Vechile` method:

```
    public async Task<RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle> UpdateVehicle(int id, RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        OnVehicleUpdated(vehicle);

        **Reset();**

        var itemToUpdate = Context.Vehicles
                          .Where(i => i.Id == vehicle.Id)
                          .FirstOrDefault();

        if (itemToUpdate == null)
        {
           throw new Exception("Item no longer available");
        }
            
        var entryToUpdate = Context.Entry(itemToUpdate);
        entryToUpdate.CurrentValues.SetValues(vehicle);
        entryToUpdate.State = EntityState.Modified;

        Context.SaveChanges();

        OnAfterVehicleUpdated(vehicle);

        return vehicle;
    }
```

As far as what was happening, for lack of a better term, the data in the `VehicleOrders` table was being 'scrambled', I'm sure it was being systematically 'scrambled' but I didn't solve that riddle. My feeling is because there are references to the same `Vehicle` multiple times in the `VehicleOrders` table. Continuing to test, the page is a grid of `Vehicles` with drill down for each one and an edit link which is a popup. I think if a drill down is open, then the problem happens, this could make sense because the drill down gets data and likely attaches some things to the DbContext that creates the "bad" updates in the `VehicleOrders` table.

Comment: We cannot understand what happened without code which changes data. Also show classes, not images.

Comment: `entryToUpdate.State = EntityState.Modified` is not needed EF Core should detect changes automatically.

Comment: Also if you have async methods, use `Async` overloads from EF Core:  `await ... FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and `await Context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Comment: The code doesn't give any reason to think that navigation properties are updated. `CurrentValues.SetValues(vehicle)` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`SetValues` doesn't dive into navigation properties, and the EntityState change is not necessary, just set the values and call `SaveChanges`. So your code can be simplified to:

```
public async Task<RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle> UpdateVehicle(int id, RadzenBlazorServerApp.Models.sql_database.Vehicle vehicle)
{
    OnVehicleUpdated(vehicle); // What code is listening to this?

    var itemToUpdate = await Context.Vehicles
                        .Where(i => i.Id == vehicle.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (itemToUpdate == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Item no longer available");
    }
        
    itemToUpdate.CurrentValues.SetValues(vehicle); // Change tracking will do it's job here.
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

    OnAfterVehicleUpdated(vehicle); // and what code is listening to this?

    return vehicle;
}
```

Note that with "itemToUpdate" we are not eager loading VehicleOrders, so in copying the values from the passed in vehicle, the entity actually being updated isn't even tracking orders, barring those orders being previously loaded prior to this call.

So the next question is what exactly do you mean by it "affects VehicleOrders", what unexpected effects are you seeing after updating the vehicle? It shouldn't matter if the collection is mapped,  If you update a vehicle and things are changing on the related data then you either have other code lurking somewhere that is making changes, or something at the database level like a Trigger doing things. This is one issue with passing entities around because if you have any code that you pass this detached vehicle into and then do something like `Attach` it and send it's `EntityState` to Modified, well bets are off that you may end up overwriting or duplicating data in the database. Passing entities seems convenient but it can be prone to confusing behavior.

What provided/populated the vehicle being passed in? Was it constructed from passed in parameters in a Web Controller method? Is it an untracked entity? or is it a Tracked entity?

A good test:

```
var itemToUpdate = await Context.Vehicles
                    .Where(i => i.Id == vehicle.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var isSameReference = object.ReferenceEquals(itemToUpdate, vehicle);
```

That *should* return `false`. If it's `true` it means the vehicle passed in is already the tracked vehicle reference and all of the code in this method is completely pointless. This could mean that the vehicle was loaded from the DbContext, or it was at some point `Attached` to the DbContext so whatever is in that vehicle instance is what EF is intending to save.

The next place I'd look is what code is executing when you signal the VehicleUpdated and AfterVehicleUpdated.